# Function that reads a string from a file of unknown length

Tags: c, string, function, file, memory-management

I've been trying to piece together a function that allows me to create a string out of a given file of unknown length.

What it's *supposed* to do, is set the size of the output string to a single character, then for each character besides EOF, increment the size of the string by 1 and add the newly read character to it.

```
void readstring(FILE *f, char *s[])
{
    int size = 1;
    int c = 0, i = 0;

    s = malloc(size*sizeof(char));

    while(c != -1)
    {
        c = fgetc(f);
        s[i] = (char)c;
        i++;

        if(i == size)
        {
            size++;
            s = realloc(s, size*sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *in = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    FILE *IN;

    IN = fopen("in.txt", "r");

    readstring(IN, in);

    printf("%s",&in);

    fclose(IN);
    free(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **1st** `EOF` is not a character

Comment: After `char in[2];` you simply cannot change the size of `in` in any way, not even hiding it inside a function. Try `char *in = malloc(2);` and remember to `free(in);` before your program terminates.

Comment: You also need to make sure you allocate 1 more character than you need to store that `\0` at the end of your function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Good news is, after making the changes you recommended, I no longer get any errors or warnings. Bad news is, it still seems to spew out a single random character instead of the content of the IN file.

I'm assuming it's due to the ```realloc()``` part of the function, but I still haven't figured out what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: You should update your code in the question to reflect the changes you have made based on the comments.

Comment: Does he have to pass a reference to a pointer as the parameter? Else he is passing a copy. Might that cause the result to be different in main?

Comment: A question is a sentence with a question mark at the end. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a question mark in your post...

Comment: This seems holy inefficient, allocating one char at a time. Consider allocating in chunks of e.g. 128 bytes.

Comment: Since `realloc` can change the pointer, you need to pas a double pointer.

Comment: Wouldn't allocating more chunks at a time result in some empty spaces in the end? Not saying that would be difficult to deal with, I assume I'd just do something along the lines of ```realloc(strlen(s)*sizeof(char))```, but I thought adding them one character at a time is more efficient.

Comment: Memory reallocation is expensive. Do it in chunks. It doesn’t matter about redundant buffer since null character signals end of string.

Comment: And in addition to memory reallocation being expensive, it also has quadratic complexity (`O(N^2)`) if you don't grow your increments. Every time that you realloc the string, you are possibly copying over a string of increasing length. The normal approach is to use increments of factor 2, which gets the complexity down to linear (`O(N)`) as every byte is only copied once or twice on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a POSIX compliant system (any modern Linux), don't try to reinvent the wheel. Just use `getline()`. It will do the tricky stuff of managing a growing buffer for you, and return a suitably `malloc()`'ed string.

---

You are assigning the result of `malloc()`/`realloc()` to `s` instead of `*s`. `s` is purely local to `readstring()`, `*s` is the pointer variable that `s` points to. Pass in the *adress* of the pointer in main. Correct code looks like this:

```
void foo(char** out_string) {
    *out_string = malloc(...);
}

int main() {
    char* string;
    foo(&string);
}
```

Without the address taking `&` and pointer dereferenciation `*`, your `main()` cannot know where `readstring()` has stored the characters.

You also need to dereference the double pointer when you set the characters of the string: Use `(*s)[i]` instead of `s[i]`, as `s[i]` denotes a pointer, not a character.

---

Also, try running your program with `valgrind`, and see if you can learn from the errors that it will spew out at you. It's a great tool for debugging memory related problems.